# Keyerror in Kivy Layout Language

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm new to the kivy framework, and I don't think I am correctly understanding how id references between the kv file and the python work. When I coded this in pure python, it worked as expected, but I'm trying to learn to use the layout language. I have Dynamically generated scatter widgets, and I need to add them to a layout.

In the python.

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):

        for index in xrange(numberOfWords):
                genColor = [255, 0, 0]
                shuffle(genColor)
                newWordWidget = WordWidget(genColor)
                if newWordWidget.label.color[0] == 255 and  newWordWidget.label.text != 'red': newWordWidget.trash = True
                if newWordWidget.label.color[1] == 255 and  newWordWidget.label.text != 'green': newWordWidget.trash = True
                if newWordWidget.label.color[2] == 255 and  newWordWidget.label.text != 'blue': newWordWidget.trash = True
                print("Trash:" + str(newWordWidget.trash))
                newWordWidget.scatter.pos = randint(0, Window.size[0]), randint(0, Window.size[1])
                self.ids.widgetscreen.add_widget(newWordWidget.scatter)
```

the kv file:

```
<FloatLayout>:
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:
<MainScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        id: widgetscreen
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

I'm getting a keyerror on the line: id: widgetscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed my problem.

in the python from my original post:

```
from kivy.clock import mainthread
```

and...

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self):
```

Nothing was wrong with the id reference. The issue was the kv file was loading after the id was referenced. `@mainthread` makes `def on_enter()` wait for the kv file to load.

Comment: This does solve the issue, however it is usually considered unidiomatic. For most purposes, use of the `ids` attribute is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested way for doing element linking goes something like this.

KV:

```
<MainScreen>:
    widgetscreen: wdscreen
    FloatLayout:
        id : wdscreen
        ...
```

Python:

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty # don't forget to add the import

class MainScreen(Screen):

    widgetscreen = ObjectProperty(None)
    ....
```

Let's take a look at what's happening here. First, in the Python code, we create a class attribute of `MainScreen`, `widgetscreen`, which defaults to `None`. Then, in our KV file, we set that attribute of `MainScreen` to `wdscreen`. In KV lang, ids work like variables, so when we set `widgetscreen` to `wdscreen`, we're actually setting it to the FloatLayout we defined with id `wdscreen`. At  runtime, kivy will fill in our Python attribute with the appropriate widget.

With that, you should be able to access `widgetscreen` from within `MainScreen` as `self.widgetscreen`. You don't even need to use `ids`.

Comment: doesn't work. Getting an 'ObjectProperty' is not defined error.

Comment: @SteveHostetler, add `ObjectProperty` to your import list. (e.g. `from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty`)